# Applying Monte Carlo to a multi-level problem

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling, monte-carlo

Here is my problem statement, and the bolded item in the bulleted list is where I'm having trouble with. I think my question comes from my poor understanding of Monte Carlo sampling and conditional probability.

**Problem Statement**: I need to perform Monte Carlo simulation for a problem where, in its simplest form, can be represented as:

$Z= f(Y1(\mu,\sigma), Y2(\mu,\sigma))$, where

$\mu_{Y1} = f(X1(\mu,\sigma), X2(\mu,\sigma))$

I know the distributions of $X1$, $X2$, and $Y2$, and also $\sigma_{Y2}$, and I want to apply Monte Carlo to get realizations of $Z$.

**Flow of analysis**:

1. Generate $N$ samples on $X1$, $X2$, and $Y2$
2. Calculate an instance of $\mu_{Y1}$ for every pair of $X1$ and $X2$ samples
3. **What to do here?** For every $\mu_{Y1}$ instance, do I

   - generate 1 sample of $Y1$ and propagate this sample with the sample of $Y2$ to get $Z$, or
   - generate $N$ samples of $Y1$, which increases the dimension of $Z$ to $N^2$?
4. Obtain my realizations of $Z$

Am I even on the right track? Any help and thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: How do you generate $Y1$ sample if you don't know distribution?

Comment: For this exercise, let's say I have a model that predicts the mean values of Y1, and the model is dependent on two random variables (X1 and X2).

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do.  However N samples will always work better.  Why $N^2$ for $Z$?

Comment: (1) I'll see if I can explain it better: I want to predict the variable Z, and I have a prediction model where Z is dependent on two random variables (Y1 and Y2, as shown by the first equation in my post). I know the mean and sigma for Y2, but for Y1 I only know the sigma. To estimate the mean for Y1, I have to use another model (second equation) where the means of Y1 is a function of two other random variables (X1 and X2), which I know the distributions fully.

Comment: (2) Now, given my known inputs of means and sigmas for X1, X2, Y2, and the sigma for Y1, I want to generate N samples of Z. To use the model shown by my first equation, I need to first estimate the mean of Y1, which requires me to perform my first and second steps under the flow of analysis. By the end of the second step, I will have N samples of the means of Y1 (1 sample for each set of X1 and X2 samples). My confusion is on the next step, as I don't know how to use these N samples of the means of Y1 in equation 1 to predict Z. Does this make sense at all?

Comment: Why not use the average of the N samples of $Y_1$?